# Owl carousel - how can I grab exact element which is currently in the view?

Tags: jquery, callback, owl-carousel

I’m using owl carousel – jquery. When an image changes I’ d like to achive an effect of sliding text, some kind of movement or effect like changing opacity for example. How can I do it using owl carousel? I wanted to use events. Every time slide changes event triggers but how can I grab exact element which is currently in the view and change the style only of this element and delete a style from the rest of them? thank you

```
constructor(){  
    this.owl =  $('.owl-carousel');
    this.owlTxt =  $('.container__slider-txt');
    this.events();
}

events(){
    let that = this;
    this.owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
        that.owlTxt.css('opacity', 1);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current slide from the event. Try this:

```
this.on('changed.owl.carousel',function(event){
    var current = event.item.index;
    // do something
});
```